# Using Expression Blend for normal website development

Tags: expression-blend

I have heard a lot about using Expression Blend to make HTML/Javascript Metro applications.

However I am curious how usable Expression Blend is to make Websites i.e. Web applications that run on all browsers, not just inside the IE derived engine in Metro.

The question : Is it usable as is or will Expression Blend spew IE specific JS/HTML that you will need to edit/change/remove manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expression Blend 2012, the current version, is not designed for creating websites.  The HTML that is used in Metro apps is markup for Windows Store apps.

If you are looking for Microsoft web design tools, look at [Expression Web](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc136529.aspx) or [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)

Comment: Do you know if the info in this answer is still current?

Comment: About Expression Blend 2012, or the newer versions?

Comment: Newer versions. I was wondering if I could create interactive UI mockups in Blend that could be easily shared with others via a web browser (even if it has to be in IE/Edge or Silverlight, though standard stuff would be nice).

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible.